# Master Server -> ( Host <-> Client ) setup for Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I'm making a game in Unity.  I've made a NodeJS server that acts as a match-maker/lobby.

Once two players have been matched though, I'd like one of them to act as host and maintain game state, while the other player acts as a client - sending through input state and receiving game state.  This is primarily to minimize server load and traffic as the game is physics-driven and transfers a lot of transform and physics data.

It doesn't appear there is existing functionality in UnityEngine.Networking to facilitate this type of system, and it's also quite a difficult thing to Google as many use "host" to mean a dedicated game server.

Any leads?

**EDIT** - I've toyed around with .NET socket libraries but not comfortable enough in what I've seen so far to be convinced I'm on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

See this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetClientServer.html

It specifically identifies the model you want is has an example of a LocalClient and Server running on the same code base.